# $ _GET missing in pagination

Tags: php

I have 2 files, the first one:
gives me the list of products

The second one:
- information relating to the product, therefore as an information page

In the first file, I implement a `<a>` tag, to redirect to the second file

and the variable: `$id_evidenza = $row_ListaEvidenze['ID_evidenza'];`

```
<a href="edit_evidenza.php?id=<?php echo $id_evidenza; ?>&te=<?php echo $_GET['te']; ?>" title="Modifica">
    <strong><?php echo outputDecode($row_ListaEvidenze['cod_evidenza']); ?></strong> 
</a
```

make a select query, and take my variable:

```
$myid_processo = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $myid_processo = $_GET['id'];
}

//42320819($database_riskmanagement,$riskmanagement);
$query_processo = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tev_Evidenze WHERE tev_Evidenze.id_struttura = ".$id_str." AND tev_Evidenze.ID_evidenza = %s", GetSQLValueString($myid_processo, "int"));
$processo = mysqli_query($riskmanagement, $query_processo) or die(mysqli_error($riskmanagement));
createLog($_COOKIE['cod_operatore'], $query_processo);

$row_processo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($processo);
$totalRows_processo = mysqli_num_rows($processo);
```

with a do / while loop, I show the results on screen and it's ok.

Now the problems begin, because right now from the page where there are the list of products, we are in the product info page, they asked me, to implement a navigation system, which gives the possibility that if I am inside the product A, going back and forth I can scroll through the other products, without going over the product list page, and so I did by implementing this navigation system:

```
if($_GET['te']==""){
    $sel_tipo_acc = " (ev.id_tipo_accreditamento = 0)";
}else{
    $sel_tipo_acc = " (ev.id_tipo_accreditamento = ".$_GET['te'].")";
}
$my_ric_att = searchControl(trim($_GET['ric_att']));
$txt_ric = "";
$txt_ric = "Risultati per ";
$r_sql = "SELECT * FROM tev_Evidenze AS ev LEFT JOIN tev_Fatt_crit AS fc 
          ON fc.ID_fatt_crit = ev.id_fatt_crit 
          WHERE ev.id_struttura = ".$_SESSION['str']." AND ".$sel_tipo_acc." AND ";

        if ($_GET['facr'] != ""){
            $r_sql .=  " fc.ID_fatt_crit = ".$_GET['facr']." AND ";
        }

$r_sql .= " ((ev.cod_evidenza LIKE '%" .$my_ric_att. "%') OR (ev.desc_evidenza LIKE '%" .$my_ric_att. "%')) ";
$txt_ric .= trim($_GET['ric_att']) ;
$r_sql .= " ORDER BY fc.ordine_fatt_crit, ev.cod_evidenza, ev.ordine_evidenza";
$txt_ric .= "<br>";

if($_GET['v']=="all"){
    $paginazione = 1;   
}else{
    $paginazione = 1;
}

$maxRows_ListaEvidenze = $paginazione;
$pageNum_ListaEvidenze = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_ListaEvidenze'])) {
  $pageNum_ListaEvidenze = $_GET['pageNum_ListaEvidenze'];
}
$startRow_ListaEvidenze = $pageNum_ListaEvidenze * $maxRows_ListaEvidenze;

//42320819($database_riskmanagement, $riskmanagement);
$query_ListaEvidenze = $r_sql;
$query_limit_ListaEvidenze = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_ListaEvidenze, $startRow_ListaEvidenze, $maxRows_ListaEvidenze);
$ListaEvidenze = mysqli_query($riskmanagement, $query_limit_ListaEvidenze) or die(mysqli_error($riskmanagement));
createLog($_COOKIE['cod_operatore'], $v_sql);

$row_processo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ListaEvidenze);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_ListaEvidenze'])) {
  $totalRows_ListaEvidenze = $_GET['totalRows_ListaEvidenze'];
} else {
  $all_ListaEvidenze = mysqli_query($riskmanagement, $query_ListaEvidenze);
  $totalRows_ListaEvidenze = mysqli_num_rows($all_ListaEvidenze);
}
$totalPages_ListaEvidenze = ceil($totalRows_ListaEvidenze/$maxRows_ListaEvidenze)-1;

$queryString_ListaEvidenze = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_ListaEvidenze") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_ListaEvidenze") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_ListaEvidenze = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_ListaEvidenze = sprintf("&totalRows_ListaEvidenze=%d%s", $totalRows_ListaEvidenze, $queryString_ListaEvidenze);
```

I have the problem in my url, I can't get all the necessary parameters in $ _GET, that is, if for example I go from product A to that B, I get this:

```
pageNum_ListaEvidenze=5&totalRows_ListaEvidenze=76&id=340&te=5

pageNum_ListaEvidenze=6&totalRows_ListaEvidenze=76&id=340&te=5
```

where the only thing that changes is the number after: `pageNum_ListaEvidenze=`

displaying another record, but the id is always stopped at the first record, I have this problem from this snippet of code, which I posted before:

```
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_ListaEvidenze'])) {
  $pageNum_ListaEvidenze = $_GET['pageNum_ListaEvidenze'];
}
```

how do i make everything dynamic in the url?

Answer (score 0):

I really understand your issue , but here is a better solution that can make the life easy .

Let's suppose that currently , you are on the info page(Page B as you describe) that show the product information .

To swip for the next product , or previous , you can try to do this :

Normaly , one the info page , you are able to get the id of the current product

```
$currentProductID = $_GET['id'];
```

Think to create a method that give you the id of the next product , the query should be like :

```
SELECT id FROM `product` WHERE `id` > $currentProductID limit 1
```

This will return the id of the next product , and then  redirect to the B page with this id returned using php redirection or by clicking on the  tag etc .

> To do that for the previous product , just inverse the query above
>   with <.

Hope that help you .